# Using Code Project (CPOL) licenced code on Google Code

Tags: open-source, licensing, google-code

I have a piece of software that I would like to open source via Google Code Project Hosting. The problem is that I have used some code from Code Project which is licenced with the Code Project Open Licence (CPOL).

Are any of the available licences I can choose from Google Code compatible with CPOL? Or do I have to find some way of removing the CPOL code before I can open source my software? I'm having a hard time figuring out if I can include the CPOL code. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read it the way that the original code (and in part if your create a derivate) requires that it's licensed under [The Code Project Open License (CPOL) 1.02](http://www.codeproject.com/info/cpol10.aspx).

Google Project hosting [requires](http://code.google.com/hosting/createProject) an [OSI-approved license](http://opensource.org/licenses/alphabetical).

As far as I can see, CPOL is not OSI-approved.

You can contact the original author/copyright holder of the code and ask to gain rights on the codebase under a different license that full-fills the requirements of your google code hosting.

Or you choose another platform that allows more licenses. I think github requires only that the code is "open source" (you can read the source code).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is very useful. I guess I'll either have to rewrite the code, or investigate github.